# How to validate a zipcode text field and add HTML in case of error on submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

The jQuery code below alerts the user in case of incorrect zip code entered by attaching the change event to it. I would like to validate zip code entered in the text field on form in a landing page and add a bit of HTML in case of error on submitting the form. Could you please guide me on how to do it.

HTML for the input:

```
<div class="ff-el-input--content"><input type="text" name="address_1[zip]" id="ff_241_address_1_zip_" class="ff-el-form-control" placeholder="Zip"></div>
```

jQuery to validate:

```
jQuery("input:text[name='address_1[zip]']").change(function(e) {
if (!jQuery(this).val().match(/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/)) { 
        alert("Please enter a valid zip code");
        jQuery("input[name='address_1[zip]']").val("");
        return false;                        
    }        
});
```

When validation fails, I need to add the div below to right after the `input text` field.
`<div class="error text-danger">This field is required</div>`

Submit element:

```
<button type="submit" class="ff-btn ff-btn-submit   ff-btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

Image showing part of the form:
[image]

Comment: Zip Code from where? Mine is: B1904CZV

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, Updated the post with an image too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are the functions `after()` and `remove()`.

```js
jQuery("input:text[name='address_1[zip]']").change(function(e) {
  if (!jQuery(this).val().match(/^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid zip code");
    jQuery("input[name='address_1[zip]']").val("");
    if ($('.error').length == 0) {
      $(this).after('<div class="error text-danger">This field is required</div>');
    }
  } else {
    $('.error').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Reza, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked

Comment: Sure. You have received a couple of answers, but I just posted an answer the way I would do it. Hope it helps.